# Vertical Layout, 2 Elements, Make the Top One Fill the Remaining Space (Bottom One Has wrap_content)

Tags: android, android-layout, height, xml-layout

I have the following dilemma. Two elements, one on top of each other. The bottom has `wrap_content` for height. I want the top element to fill the remaining space without the two elements overlapping (which happens if I use `FrameLayout` for example).

The width is `match_parent` for all elements.

Here's a mockup (some attributes truncated for clarity):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <CustomView android:layout_height="???????" /> 

  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<CustomView 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    .../>
```

Comment: "Invalid layout param in a FrameLayout: layout_weight". Note that the parent `LinearLayout` doesn't have a `weightSum` defined, which may be the reason for this. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: No, you don't need `weightSum` to be there. This should only be a problem if the immediate parent is a `FrameLayout`, not a `LinearLayout` as you've shown above. If you need it in a `FrameLayout`, wrap the weighted view in a `LinearLayout`.